# How to replace values in a np 2d array based on condition for every row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, max

I have a numpy 2d array (named `lda_fit`) with probabilities, where I want to replace the probabilities with 0 or 1, based on the max value in each line.

```
array([[0.06478282, 0.80609092, 0.06511851, 0.06400775],
       [0.50386571, 0.02621445, 0.44400621, 0.02591363],
       [0.259538  , 0.04266385, 0.65470484, 0.04309331],
       ...,
       [0.01415491, 0.01527508, 0.22211579, 0.74845422],
       [0.01419367, 0.01537099, 0.01521318, 0.95522216],
       [0.25      , 0.25      , 0.25      , 0.25      ]])
```

So after all the first line should look like `[0,1,0,0]`, the second like `[1,0,0,0]` and so on. I have tried, and this works, but only for a given threshold (0.5):

```
np.where(lda_fit < 0.5,0,1)
```

But as I might not have the largest value being greater than 0.5, I want to specify a new threshold for each line. Unfortunately this gives me the max value of the whole array.

```
np.where(lda_fit < np.max(lda_fit),0,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.max` with specifying axis:

```
(lda_fit.max(1,keepdims=True)==lda_fit)+0
```

**Note**: if there is more than one max in a row, it will return 1 for all of them. For alternative solution follow the next method.

output for example input in question:

```
[[0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

In case of multiple max in a row, if you want to have only first one as 1 and the rest of max as 0, you can use `argmax`:

```
(lda_fit.argmax(axis=1)[:,None] == range(lda_fit.shape[1]))+0
```

or equally:

```
lda_fit_max = np.zeros(lda_fit.shape, dtype=int)
lda_fit_max[np.arange(len(lda_fit)),lda_fit.argmax(axis=1)]=1
```

output:

```
[[0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: That works like what I wished. Thanks a lot. Code looks a little different than expected though... I tried axis=1 in np.where(lda_fit < np.max(lda_fit),0,1) but it complained...

Comment: I guess I did not correctly use axis, I did `np.where(lda_fit < np.max(lda_fit,1,axis=1),0,1)`

Comment: @Sebastian The correct one would be the one I mentioned in the comment above. That to any of suggested solutions should work.